# Angular2 observable not working

Tags: javascript, angular, peerjs

I am using peerjs library to build a chat. I'm trying to do an observable to trigger an event every time I get a new message.

```
this.data = new Observable(observer => {
                   this.peer.on('connection', (data) => {
                    alert("TRIGGER");
                    observer.next(data);   
                });
             })


             this.peerMessages = this.data.subscribe(message => {
                alert(message);
            });
```

I can see the first alert but the second one never triggers. I don't get any error from the browser console. What am I doing wrong?

Im trying to use an observer because instead of alert(message) I want to change a variable from the angular component.

Comment: The code looks good, can you create a live example?

Comment: Hi. I am using the following project https://github.com/rajayogan/angular2-videochat in app.component.ts the method   this.peer.on('connection', function(conn) { I am trying to create an observable from that.

Comment: Is the problem that it works in that project, but doesn't work when you do something similar in a different project? Or does it not even work in that project?

Comment: That project is not using an observer because it just triggers ->  console.log(data); the problem is that I need to create an observer because I cannot access outside variables from the this.peer.on function.

Comment: Ok, if possible please create a live example that demonstrates your specific problem, I took your example and ran it on my laptop, and it's fine (except I don't have a "connection" event, so I triggered a custom event). If you remove `this.peer.on('connection', (data) => {` and just do `observer.next('test')` does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't work either. why is that? should it run once? maybe I'm doing something wrong with observables.

Comment: It should run once. I did the following and it worked: `this.data = new Observable(observer => observer.next('test')); this.peerMessages = this.data.subscribe(message => alert(message));`. So I think you should create a live example that demonstrates the problem. Maybe there is something else going on (not importing the right thing, some error you aren't noticing, etc.).

Comment: I found the error! I wasn't importing  Observable, Subscription haha. Thank you!! I need to sleep. :D

Comment: You're welcome :) I added an answer in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks good, but make sure you import everything you need. For example, if using `rxjs`:

```
import { Observable, ... } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```